# Inherit config in nginx

Tags: nginx, wsgi

I'm using nginx and uwsgi as wsgi container. and I set basic auth to sub-directory.
so my configuration is like this:

```
location /autotweet {
    location /autotweet/teach {
        auth_basic "Restricted area";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/wsgi/earthreader.htpasswd;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/autotweet.sock;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /autotweet;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/autotweet.sock;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /autotweet;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}
```

But some line is copy-pasted. I don't want to copy-paste lines in every other config files.
Is there easier way to solving this?

Comment: In this code you could just remove inner duplicated lines

Comment: @AlexeyTen I already tried that. but it's not worked as expected.

Comment: Well, `uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/autotweet.sock;` should be enough. Other directives should be inhereted.